# Given 35 / 4, I want an "8" returned

Tags: java

Rather than an "8.75" returned.

Which method?  Thanks.

Comment: could you give the code that returns `8.75`?

Comment: I didn't write that snip of consequence yet.  I wanted to know what to write.

Comment: doh.. well, next time spare 30 seconds and write it.

Comment: @Bozho - I guess, he wanted to admit, that he didn't write some code so far. No statement = no code -> nothing to show.

Comment: @Andread_D I got that, and was confused why he didn't just try it.

Comment: Judging from the count spinner, somebody really, really doesn't like the question. It really affects him in deep way.  I guess you don't like the questions answerers either, since they took time to answer it.

Comment: -2.  Wow.  Down from +1.  What a stupid question, huh?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm not completely wrong, `35/4` always evaluates to 8. Even in

```
double result = 35 / 4;
```

you will get this result (as double, i.e. `8.0`). This is because `35` and `4` are both integers and therefore integer division is applied. The expression is first evaluated as integer and only the result is cast to a double value.

On the other hand, if you want the correct result `8.75` you' ll have to write

```
 double result = 35. / 4;
```

in order to force floating point division to be applied. This is a common pitfall by the way.

Of course, if you have double values, like in

```
double a = 35;
double b = 4;
```

you need to either explicitely cast to an `int` or use `Math.floor()` as suggested in previous posts.

Comment: @user225626 Yes. Why don't you just try it out yourself?

Comment: I did before I accepted.  I just wanted to make sure that's the language design.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
Math.floor(..)
```

> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.

Or, if you need to manipulate ints, not doubles, then simply assign to int:

```
int a = 35 / 4;
```

Actually, if you work with the numbers directly, or with int variables, you will get an `int` result automatically.

Answer (score 4):

cast to int

```
(int)
```

example :

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-code-snippets-tutorials/314-how-type-cast-convert-double-integer.html

Answer (score 2):

explicitly cast the expression as int

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 35/4
```

integer division causes 8 to be returned instead of 8.75

Answer (score 0):

using

```
int myInt = (int) Math.floor(value);
```

8.75 will be rounded to 8. Casting to int removes decimals in case value is a double.